# Azure DevOps pipelines - Build triggered multiple times

Tags: azure, devops

I am using different YAML files (with different tasks) in different branches.
While triggering it executes multiple times. I don't know what is the reason.

I am using different triggers for different pipelines. eg:

In branch SFCC:

```
trigger:
- SFCC
```

In branch SFCC-QA:

```
trigger:
- SFCC-QA
```

In branch SFCC-DEV:

```
trigger:
- SFCC-DEV
```

When I run the pipeline for SFCC triggered, the same pipeline would start running in another pipeline also with same trigger, because of that app is deploying 2-3 times instead of single time.

Could you please help me with this.

SFCC-QA pipeline:

[image]

SFCC pipeline:

[image]

You can see in first screenshot(for the date 9th sep and 14th sep), the pipeline is for QA and here pipeline is executing for other branch, which is not mentioned in this particular pipeline. While in the second screenshot pipeline is executing fine for the same date. So you can see 2 times same pipeline is execting on 9th and 14th sep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure build pipeline definition is associated with a repo and YAML file in that repo. The branch is associated at the time only when the pipeline is run. So, it is not something you associate at the time of pipeline definition.

I think in all 3 of your pipelines, the YAML file path is same. You have different trigger (and different other content) in the YAML file in different branches, but your file name/path is same. Hence the same file will trigger the build for each branch where relevant within pipeline.

To get desired results you can use different file name for your YAML file for each pipeline definition. So in SFCC branch have SFCC.yaml and in SFCC-QA branch, have SFCC-QA.yaml.

Comment: After using different file names for different branches, it's working fine now. Thank you